# Unable to create new connection in LogicApp for Mysql

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

when try to create new connection for mysql from Logicapps, we are getting below error message.
Failed to create connection: {"error":{"code":"ApiConnectionIsInConflictState","message":"The api connection 'azuremysql' is being cleaned up. Please try again later or use different connection name."

If anyone face similar issue, please help me on this.

We tried to create new connection after copy the logic app code into another subscription and results the above issue when trying to create new connection.